# Proper way to validate an input is numeric in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive in angular:

```
define(function(require) {
   var angular = require('angular');

    angular.module('is-numeric', [])
        .directive('isNumeric', [function() {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                    elem.on('keyup', function(e) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('isnumeric', !isNaN(e.target.value));
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
});
```

Do I really need to add an event handler for the keyup or is there a better way?

Comment: `<input type="number" ng-model="numberModel" />`, this only takes number as input, or do you have any specific requirement to validate

Comment: i meant in general and not just for isnuneric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use validators:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
   ctrl.$validators.isnumeric = function(modelValue, viewValue){
       return !isNaN(viewValue);
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you should not use any directives.
My suggestion is that use the built in ng-pattern validator, which will handle the case you described.

You can check here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

```
<input ng-model="validatedNumber" ng-pattern=$scope.numberValidation/>
```

and in you controller you should define the regular expression like this:

```
$scope.numberValidation = /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
```

Edit: what I forgot in my explanation is that, you should put this into a form, then when you would like to validate/send the form you should check the form validity like this:

```
if(formname.$valid())
```

where formname is the name of the DOM element which is defined as a form

```
<form name="formname"> [...] </form>
```